# Modern toolkit store load events not fired

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I used Ext JS 5.x with Sencha Touch and try to migrate to a universal modern app as it is suggested by Sencha. Yet it feels like several things changed and aren't working as supposed.

I'm using a virtual store for loading data via AJAX into a simple list. I now want to select the first (or with conditions a different record) when the list is loaded.

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.model.User', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['name', 'email']
})

Ext.define('Fiddle.view.ListController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
  alias: 'controller.test-list',
  listen: {
    store: {
        'test-users': {
            beforeload: function() {
                //Doesn't work
                console.log('before')
            }
        }
    }
},
onListItemTap: function(list, record) {
    this.fireEvent('select', this);
    console.log('selected');
}
});

Ext.define('Fiddle.store.Users', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.virtual.Store',
  alias: 'store.test-users',
  model: 'Fiddle.model.User',
  pageSize: 125,
  leadingBufferZone: 125,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'data1.json',
    reader: {
        rootProperty: 'result.users',
        successProperty: 'result.success',
        totalProperty: 'result.total'
    }
  },
  listeners: {
    load: function(){
        // Doesn't trigger
        console.log('loaded');


    },
    scope: this
  }
});
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.List', {
  extend: 'Ext.List',
  xtype: 'test-list',
  controller: 'test-list',
  viewModel: {
    stores: {
        users: {
            type: 'test-users',
            listeners: {
                load: function(){
                    // Doesn't trigger
                    console.log('loaded');
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    }
        },
  bind: {
    store: '{users}'
  },
  itemTpl: '{name}. {email}',
  infinite: true,
  listeners: {
    select: 'onListItemTap'
  },
  initialize: function(){
    var me = this;
    this.callParent(arguments);

    /*Doesn't work as store seems to be not bound yet
    this.select(0)
    this.store.on('load', function(){
       console.log('loaded');
       this.select(0);
    });
    */

    //Does work, but dirty
    Ext.defer(function () {
        //this.select(0);
        //console.log(me.getStore());
    }, 500, me);
  },
  afterRender: function() {
    this.callParent()
    // Doesn't work, shouldn't the store be available/loaded after its 
  rendered?
    console.log(this.getStore()); //null
  }
})
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function () {
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'test-list'
    })
  }
})
```

Problems:
1) I have is that the store is not available in the initialize function of the view, therefor I cannot add an on listener there.

2) Neither in the store itself, nor in the viewmodel, nor in the controller I can add a listener. If I override the stores load method and fire the load event manually all listeners start working

```
// Fiddle.store.Users.load
load: function() {
  this.callParent(arguments);
  this.fireEvent('load');
}
```

Are all those standard listeners not implemented yet in the modern toolkit or am I missing something?

3) I tried to hook into the `afterRender` method of the view but the store isn't available there as well even tho per naming the list including the data should've been rendered already..

4) Store seems to get autoloaded all the time no matter if I add autoLoad: false or true.

I never had any problem with prior versions, is the modern toolkit in it's current state just buggy or am I doing something wrong?

See [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2g39)

Answer (score 0):

1. If the store is a global store, you can add it to the application's [`stores`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.app.Application.html#cfg-stores) property, then it would be made available before any view is instantiated.
2. From the source code it seems that virtual store does not currently fire a `load` event. Not sure whether this is a bug, you may have to ask Sencha Support. Since you made me curious, please report back the answer here.
3. `afterRender` is called after the list is rendered, but the store is bound only after rendering of the component tree is complete. See my answer to (1) if you need the store available earlier.
4. Virtual store does "auto load" when the store is bound to the list because of the paging. The list knows which page size is required, and sets the page size of the store, which triggers a reload. You can find out for yourself by adding `console.trace()` in your custom load function; it will output a full stack trace of the calls. You have to ask Sencha Support whether there is any possibility to get rid of the automatic reload.

On a side note, selecting the first record on each `load` event is weird for a virtual store. Virtual store dynamically loads additional pages of records when you scroll. If the mere load of a new page causes selection changes, this would look weird to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Agree on your side node - I wanted it on the first load/afterRender of the initial list but that doesn't work unless I defer the select which is why I was looking for some kind of event to catch. Sadly the whole store binding stuff doesn't seem to work properly at the moment.
I don't want the store to be "global". It's just that the view never knows when the store is loaded and therfor cannot select a record. Half of the events are not fired, either for the virtual store or for the dataview.list (e.g. show). Painted works but again the record is not selectable..

Comment: Overall it's hard to believe that this is such a mess. Rendering a list and selecting the first record shouldn't be a big deal at all. I just don't want to use some ugly defer methods but when the data is available and visible to the user.

Comment: @gulty If it's just rendering a list and selecting the first record, why do you use a virtual store, and not a normal `Ext.data.Store`?

Comment: because I have an infinite list with loads of ajax records sent by an api. when selecting 1 of them I open a panel on the right side to edit the data. Also, I would have the same problem in various places if I can't properly execute functions at the right time.

Comment: @gulty Not sure why this means that you cannot use a store. I am using dozens of stores, loading records from stores into forms, editing and saving them, and everything works like a charm. I don't use virtual stores, however...

Comment: I was using buffered stores for better performance. having 100k list entries loaded at once will cause performance issues. That's why I saw that virtual store is the modern toolkit alternative for having buffered lists. I don't want to get 100k entries at once due to the high traffic. Also I want the dom elements to be re-used, else browser will just crash. I want to get it when needed on scrolling further down in chunks..